# Using a tileset for textures for a mesh

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm trying to create a isometric game in Love2D. I need to use meshes because I want to be able to rotate the camera view, but I could not figure out how to use a tileset to provide textures for the mesh.

The mesh class accepts a texture only, unlike the sprite batch class, which accepts quads to direct it on what part of the texture to use. Is there a way to give the mesh class this information or even slice up the tileset into individual images to be used with meshes?

Comment: Meshes usually have texture coordinates.

Comment: Not in love2d apparently.

Comment: https://love2d.org/wiki/Mesh:setVertices Looks like the third and fourth component of every mesh is a texture coordinate...

Comment: Yup, I'm an idiot. I just read that. I thought it was the same format as the polygon function. Thanks for the the help by the way.